# keep the original string format after modified?

Tags: php, string

keep the original string format after modified?

```
$source1= "03aaa\r\n
04bbb\r\n
05ccc\r\n
04eee\r\n
05fff\r\n
04ggg\r\n
05hhh\r\n
08eee\r\n"
```

Can be

`$source2= "03aaa04bbb05ccc04eee05fff04ggg05hhh08eee"`

I want to keep the original format(if there are linebreak keep it like origin)  after I made modified(added `07`) the $source .

if input is like source1 format:

ouput:

```
$source1= "03aaa\r\n
  04bbb\r\n
  05ccc\r\n
  04eee\r\n
  05fff\r\n
  07fff\r\n
  04ggg\r\n
  05hhh\r\n
  07hhh\r\n
  08eee\r\n"
```

if input is like source2 format:

```
$source2= "03aaa04bbb05ccc07fff04eee05fff07fff04ggg05hhh007fff8eee"
```

How Can I got the expected result and keep the format like the origin?

Anyone could help me please?

thanks

Comment: I don't understand what the question is?

Comment: How Can I got the expected result and keep the format like the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes to avoid translating special characters and variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the strings `$source1` and `$source2`, you could do so as such:

```
if (str_replace("\r\n", "", $source1) == $source2)
{
    // Do your thing
}
```